# Как сделать XSD-схему из XMLфайла?

Tags: xml, xsd

У меня есть XML-Файл ([вот он](http://www.sdfm.gov.ua/content/file/Site_docs/2016/20160913/terror107_13092016/zBlackList107.xml))
Нужно сделать для него XSD-схему и потом проверить этот же файлик новой схемой.

Я пробовал импортировать XML-Файл в MS Access, а потом экспортировать схему, но там бред полный, а не схема.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как это можно сделать?

Comment: А что вам мешает составить ее самостоятельно?

Answer (score 1):

Я использовал онлайн-конструктор:
http://www.freeformatter.com/xsd-generator.html#ad-output

Спасибо
(надо было сразу так))